# SQL: Rearranging table to get unique combinations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that essentially contains two fields; transactionnumber and productnumber. A transaction can contain several products. Currently the table is given as follows:

```
 ---------
| T1 | P1 |
| T1 | P2 |
| T2 | P2 |
| T2 | P3 |
| T2 | P4 |
| T3 | P1 |
| T3 | P4 |
| T4 | P1 |
| T4 | P3 |
| T4 | P5 |
 ---------
```

Instead I want to be able to count how the products are being sold together and therefore want each two combination of products for each transaction. (Sorry if I'm unclear) Here's how I want it:

```
 ------------
| T1 | P1, P2 |
| T2 | P2, P3 |
| T2 | P2, P4 |
| T2 | P3, P4 |
| T3 | P1, P4 |
| T4 | P1, P3 |
| T4 | P1, P5 |
| T4 | P3, P5 |
 ------------
```

How can this be done? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Add a row (T5, P2) to your sample data, and adjust the result.

Comment: I'm only looking at transactions with several products so that isn't necessary

Comment: So your table will never include a unique T value? How do you avoid that?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: Why doesn't the expected result contain `t4, p1,p3,p5`?  Instead three separate rows for T4?

Comment: Because I want to see how products are bought together. The suggested methods won't help with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all combinations of products for a given transaction by joining the table to itself on the transaction id.

```
select t1.t, t1.p, t2.p, count(*)
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t1.t = t2.t and t1.p < t2.p
group by t1.t, t1.p, t2.p
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm checking the result to see if it works

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query

```
     WITH TAB AS (
      SELECT A.* , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TRANSACTION_NUM ORDER BY PRODUCT_NUM) RN  FROM TEST_INT A)

     SELECT X.TRANSACTION_NUM, X.PRODUCT_NUM||','||Y.PRODUCT_NUM FROM TAB X, TAB Y
      WHERE X.RN+1 = Y.RN
      AND X.TRANSACTION_NUM = Y.TRANSACTION_NUM
      ORDER BY X.TRANSACTION_NUM
```

Scripts for your reference

```
      CREATE TABLE TEST_INT 
      (
      TRANSACTION_NUM VARCHAR(50),
      PRODUCT_NUM VARCHAR(50));

      INSERT INTO TEST_INT VALUES ('T1','P1');
       INSERT INTO TEST_INT values ('T1','P2');
       INSERT INTO TEST_INT VALUES ('T2','P2');
       INSERT INTO TEST_INT values ('T2','P3');
       INSERT INTO TEST_INT VALUES ('T2','P4');
       INSERT INTO TEST_INT VALUES ('T3','P1');
       INSERT INTO TEST_INT VALUES ('T3','P4');

      COMMIT;
```

[image: myoutput]

Explanation : In the above query we are just populating the row number grouping on the transaction_num and then we are using self join to join the current row with the next row. Hope you understood the logic.

Note: I have tried this in Oracle.